# Federated Authentication in SharePoint 2013 ( with ADFS) - Operation Timeout when getting FedAuth cookie

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, adfs

We are encountering a bit of an odd issue on our integration code with SharePoint.

We've managed to get the integration working using SAML tokens, see code below.

The problem is that sometimes it times out when getting the FedAuth cookie or making the request to SharePoint.

The timeouts might point to load or network issues but they are reproducible.

The first unit test on the unit test suite gets the cookie without any problem every single time, but it fails on the second.

To make this more mystifying, it seems to work fine whenever I have fiddler capturing traffic.

Even more annoying is the fact that if i run the second unit test and not the first, the test works fine.

It's as if SharePoint refuses to issue another cookie for the same client until a certain amount of time has passed, unless going through Fiddler.

I should add, that I have tried both storing the cookie for subsequent requests and getting it again for each request, it seems to make no difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static ClientContext CreateClientContext(SharePointClaimsConnection connection)
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");
        }           

        logger.DebugFormat("Create Client Context for connection: {0}", connection);

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(connection.WebUrl);

        try
        {
            if (connection.SecurityTokenServiceEndPoint != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(connection.Realm))
            {
                CookieInfo token = GetToken(connection);

                if (token == null)
                {
                    lock (syncRoot)
                    {
                        token = GetToken(connection);

                        if (token == null)
                        {
                            token = GetFedAuthCookie(connection);

                            if (token != null)
                            {
                                tokens[connection] = token;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (token != null)
                {

                    context.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.KeepAlive = true;

                        for (int i = 0; i < e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string key = e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.GetKey(i);
                            string value = e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Get(i);
                            logger.DebugFormat("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, value);
                        }

                        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

                        foreach (var cookie in token.Cookies)
                        {
                            logger.Debug("Adding cookie: " + cookie.Name);
                            logger.Debug("Domain: " + connection.WebUrl.Host);
                            logger.Debug("Expires: " + cookie.Expires.ToString());

                            Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
                            newCookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
                            newCookie.Path = "/";
                            newCookie.Secure = true;
                            newCookie.HttpOnly = true;
                            newCookie.Domain = connection.WebUrl.Host;
                            container.Add(newCookie);
                        }

                        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = container;
                    };
                }
            }

            return context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            if (context != null)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }

            throw;
        }

    }

 private static CookieInfo GetFedAuthCookie(SharePointClaimsConnection connection)
    {

        string result = GetSamlToken(connection);

        //Take this token and pass it to SharePoint STS
        string stringData = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "wa=wsignin1.0&wctx={0}&wresult={1}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(connection.WebUrl, "/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F").ToString()),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result));
        HttpWebRequest sharepointRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(connection.WebUrl, "/_trust/")) as HttpWebRequest;
        sharepointRequest.Method = "POST";
        sharepointRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        sharepointRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        sharepointRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // This is important

        using (Stream newStream = sharepointRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = sharepointRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (webResponse.Cookies["FedAuth"] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new CookieInfo()
        {
            Cookies = webResponse.Cookies.Cast<Cookie>().ToList(),
        };
    }

    private static string GetSamlToken(SharePointClaimsConnection connection)
    {
       string result;

        Uri STSService = new Uri(connection.SecurityTokenServiceEndPoint, WindowsTransport);

        using (WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
            new WindowsWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.Transport),
            new EndpointAddress(STSService)))
        {
            trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
            trustChannelFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory<IWSTrustChannelContract>();

            //Request Security Token
            RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken();
            rst.KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer;
            rst.RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue;
            rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(connection.Realm);

            var channel = trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            WSTrust13RequestSerializer trustSerializer = new WSTrust13RequestSerializer();

            using (Message message = Message.CreateMessage(
                MessageVersion.Default, WSTrust13Constants.Actions.Issue,
                new RequestBodyWriter(trustSerializer, rst)))
            {
                Message response2 = channel.EndIssue(channel.BeginIssue(message, null, null));
                XmlDictionaryReader reader = response2.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
                result = reader.ReadOuterXml();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid. Guy that came after me reckoned that it was due to firewall issues but not sure whether he got to the bottom of it or not (lost touch with him)